# Simple custom matcher does not work

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rspec-rails, matcher

I wrote a simple matcher for http response:

```
RSpec::Matchers.define :http_answer? do |answer|
  match do
    response.status == answer
  end
end
```

But it always is :ok
I used it in request specs.
Where am I wrong?
Is it possible to write such matcher correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Please read [Relish Project: Rspec Rails 3.6](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/matchers/have-http-status-matcher)

There is a built-in `have_http_status` matcher for what you are trying to do.

```
require "rails_helper"

RSpec.describe ApplicationController, :type => :controller do

  controller do
    def index
      render :json => {}, :status => 209
    end
  end

  describe "GET #index" do
    it "returns a 209 custom status code" do
      get :index
      expect(response).to have_http_status(209)
    end
  end

end
```

If for some reason you still wish to write your own matcher for a controller response status be sure that:

**Controller specs are marked by :type => :controller or if you have set
config.infer_spec_type_from_file_location! by placing them in spec/controllers.**

...and the fine documentation for [Define Matcher](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/2-4/docs/custom-matchers/define-matcher)

Comment: I know about `have_http_status`. `http_asnwer?` was an example for studying. Also I used have_http_status in request/feature specs, not controller those, and it works. What I cannot understand - why global (or not?) `response` variable is not visible inside my matcher.